# Nginx: Multiple Django Projects with project root?

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

Usually i'm using cherokee. Due to some critical issues with the latest chrome release i had to change my productive server to nginx for the time being.

Currently trying to get my configuration working as it did in cherokee. 
I'm using a very simple uwsgi handler:

```
    location /project1 {
            include uwsgi_params;
            uwsgi_pass localhost:3032;
    }
```

Works fine, the project is available on myurl.com/project1.
But django takes myurl.com as project root.

Example how i want it to work:
Multiple projects on one subdomain: project1 on /project1, project2 on /project2, etc.

The Django regex rule "^$" should work on every project like:

In Project1: ^$ -> /project1

In Project2: ^$ -> /project2 etc.

Is there a way to get this in nginx working?

Cheers,

Comment: `Multiple projects on one subdomain: project1 on /project1, project2 on /project2, etc.` : those are not subdomains but subfolders. quite a different thing. If you made virtual hosts and real subdomains everything would be much easier

Comment: i ment like:
apps.myydomain.com/project1, apps.mydomain.com/project2 = multiple projects on one subdomain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nginx does not set SCRIPT_NAME automatically as Cherokee.

You can force it with

uwsgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /project1;

you then need to rewrite the PATH_INFO, uWSGI can do this automatically for you setting

uwsgi_modifier1 30

So full nginx config:

```
 location /project1 {

        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /project1;
        uwsgi_modifier1 30;
        uwsgi_pass localhost:3032;
}
```

Another approach would be doing the whole job in uWSGI passing --manage-script-name as option and leaving the nginx config untouched.